# audio still playing after jquery mobile page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, audio, html5-audio

I will preface by apologizing if this is indeed asked and answered somewhere else...I have been rewording and googling for days for a solution to this problem with no luck.

I took on the code writing responsibilities for my webdesign capstone class, in which we are converting a print publication to digital format. We decided to go with the jquery-mobile framework. I had no experience with jquery previous to this endeavor but I learn quick and have enjoyed it immensely. I am using jquery-ui for our site, which uses one, long index.html file with data-role="page" navigation. Within the site are written works, some of which have audio narration.

I have used the html audio tag as such:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="audio/source.mp3" />
  <source src="audio/source.ogg" />
</audio>
```

The audio plays just fine, but when I navigate to another "page" the audio does not stop unless the entire site is refreshed or the pause button is clicked. What I am understanding is going on is that, while visually, the site is going from page to page, the browser is just moving throughout a single html file only showing the parts it is told to show.

Is there some basic js code that I can insert into my page somewhere that will tell it that when a link or button is clicked, to stop any audio that is playing? Let me reiterate that navigation is all done within one html file, not by by linking to different html files.

(1000 apologizes for the lengthy story....thought I should be specific)

Thanks for any and all help and suggestions

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to navigate to another 'page'? Once you navigate away you could do something like `$('audio').stop();`

Comment: Each page is divided by a `<div data-role="page" id="some-page"></div>` and the navigation is done through `<a href="#some-page">Some Page></a>`

Comment: (sorry...still figuring out how to do the stackoverflow thing)

Comment: I am glad I have been of help :) jQuery is fun and easy to understand. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you sir. It has been a lot of fun learning it but due to the time constraints on the project, I have only gotten through the highlights. Will get more in depth after the semester is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When navigating to another page `pagebeforehide` will trigger. During this stage, find `audio` in that page and `.pause()` them.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', function () {
 $(this).find('audio').each(function () {
  $(this)[0].pause();
 });
});
```

Comment: Oh my freaking god you are now in my will!!!! It's not much, but you are getting it all!!   Thank you so much Omar!

Comment: I seriously have been going at this problem for over a week now and I just don't understand js/jquery enough yet to translate different functions to the precise syntax I need....so again, THANK YOU!

Comment: Update: The code only pauses the first instance of the audio tag but nothing after. It was pure coincidence that I happened to be testing it on the first instance. How would I go about targeting all instances of the audio tag. Looping through an array of some sort I would think, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Doran lol thanks buddy. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Like I said...jquery has been fun learning it, and I learn quickly and understand what everything is doing when reading through the code, I just don't know the syntax enough to make my own yet.